# Bootstrap AFFIX and window onload event not working

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm quite new to bootstrap and I'm using affix to stick a header ontop of a page when user scrolls down.

sticked SECTION **HTML**:

```
<section class="m-book-now full-width affix" data-spy="affix">
```

I managed to do this effect with the following code:

```
$(function() {
  $('section.m-book-now').affix({
    offset: {
      top: $('section.m-book-now').offset().top
    }
  }); 
});
```

the HTML becomes correctly like this:

```
<section class="m-book-now full-width affix-top" data-spy="affix">
```

**BUT**, in some pages I have an image slider ontop of this 'm-book-now' module. Problem is that offset().top is giving me wrong offset numbers because the image on top is still loading.
I tried to solve this issue using a **window onload event** (so everything is already rendered). **but following code doesn't work:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('section.m-book-now').affix({
    offset: {
      top: $('section.m-book-now').offset().top
    }
  });
});
```

With the **window.load** event, as soon as the HTML renders it appears like this:

```
<section class="m-book-now full-width affix" data-spy="affix">
```

It **incorrectly removes the affix-top** and sticks the module on top without scrolling.
Why is that? How can I solve the proper calculation of offset().top in conjunction with window load event?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change your code in this way:

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

became:

```
$(window).on("load", function (e) {})
```

In this way it must work.

Comment: Doflamingo19, still not working.The HTML still rendered like this: 

<section class="m-book-now full-width affix" data-spy="affix">

instead of <section class="m-book-now full-width affix-top" data-spy="affix">